# Mongoose aggregate $match $get $lte date

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

Am trying to match the date if the request comes with a startDate endDate query. However i'm getting empty datas on return using the below method.

```
try {
    console.log(req.query.startDate);
    console.log(new Date(req.query.startDate));
    console.log(new Date(req.query.startDate).toISOString());

    let match = {};
    if (req.query.userId) {
        match.userId = req.query.userId;
    }

    if (req.query.startDate && req.query.endDate) {
        match.createdAt = {
            $gte: new Date(req.query.startDate),
            $lt: new Date(req.query.endDate)
        };
    }

    const docs = await Sale.aggregate([{
            $match: match
        }
    ]);
    return res.status(200).json({
        docs
    });
}


From console log:
2019-01-01
2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: Why are you doing that with an aggregate, what are you aggregating (or is some code omitted)?

Comment: Let's see a doc or 2 of input.   I suspect the date bounding logic around `createdAt` is broken.   Or possibly, `match.userId` is being set to a bad value and that is stopping the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make dates an ISO strings

```
try {
console.log(req.query.startDate);
console.log(new Date(req.query.startDate));
console.log(new Date(req.query.startDate).toISOString());

let match = {};
if (req.query.userId) {
    match.userId = req.query.userId;
}

if (req.query.startDate && req.query.endDate) {
    match.createdAt = {
        $gte: req.query.startDate.toISOString(),
        $lt: req.query.endDate.toISOString()
    };
}

const docs = await Sale.aggregate([{
        $match: match
    }
]);
return res.status(200).json({
    docs
});
```

}